# delete Airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I am quite new in Airflow. However I tried to delete some DAGs in airflow (manually; using just bottom) ,but after deletion I got message (so the physically DAG do not exist anymore)

Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/reports_general/templates/data_quality_report_airflow__.py] Invalid control character at: line 2 column 116 (char 118)

Anyone has idea how to resolve?

Comment: please provide the code and show what you have tried and where it failed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the .py dag file from the dag storage volume and then also from the UI. In the version we use the UI only deletes the data for that dag from the metadata db.